# Is there a more efficient way to write this multiplication table?

Tags: python

I´m trying to make a multiplication table like this one

```
2 X 1 = 2          3 X 1 = 3           4 X 1 = 4           5 X 1 = 5           
2 X 2 = 4          3 X 2 = 6           4 X 2 = 8           5 X 2 = 10          
2 X 3 = 6          3 X 3 = 9           4 X 3 = 12          5 X 3 = 15          
2 X 4 = 8          3 X 4 = 12          4 X 4 = 16          5 X 4 = 20
```

Is there a more efficient and cleaner way to do this, this is my code.

```
#By 1
for a in range(2, 6):
   print(f"{a} X {1} = {a*1}", end="          ")
print("")

#By 2
for b in range(2, 6):
   print(f"{b} X {2} = {b*2}", end="          ")
print("")

#By 3
for c in range(2, 6):
   print(f"{c} X {3} = {c*3}", end="          ")
print("")

#By 4
for d in range(2, 6):
   print(f"{d} X {4} = {d*4}", end="          ")
print("")
```

I´m learning how to code in python.

Comment: Use another for loop, just like you did for a, b, c and d.

Comment: Hello @germ02 and welcome to Stack Overflow (or SO)! Your problem is associated with performance by improving code. So you must refer this question to Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials; it's not a tutorial service.  You simply need more practice with loops and variables.  First, you can reuse variables: don't use a new variable for each loop.  Now, look at the differences among your four loops: only one value changes, your multiplier.  Make that the index of another loop.  Nest your loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are repeating the output, a nested loop will remove the code repetition.

**Code:**

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(2, 6):
        print(f"{j} X {i} = {i*j}\t", end="")
    print("")
```

**Output:**

```
2 X 1 = 2   3 X 1 = 3   4 X 1 = 4   5 X 1 = 5   
2 X 2 = 4   3 X 2 = 6   4 X 2 = 8   5 X 2 = 10  
2 X 3 = 6   3 X 3 = 9   4 X 3 = 12  5 X 3 = 15  
2 X 4 = 8   3 X 4 = 12  4 X 4 = 16  5 X 4 = 20
```

**Explanation:**

- `\t` is used to print a tab after each output.
- `end=""` will skip printing new line.